# Templates are not being read in wagtail

Tags: templates, wagtail

I've created an app saved a file in that app, and written some code. When I save the code reload my browser, it does not give me a TemplateDoesNotExist error, then when I make the template any way, save and reload browser, it does not read, or see the template.

I've tried re-doing the whole project from scratch (I'm not that far into it), more than once, and the same thing happened. I've reached out to numerous people, from the tutorial teacher, to slack, to duckduckgo (I don't use google) to looking for the answer here.

Not sure what code needs to be shown here, but... this is the file I created within the app I created.

```
from wagtail.core import blocks


class TitleandTextBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    """Title and Text and nothing else"""

    title = blocks.CharBlock(required=True, help_text='Add your title')
    text = blocks.TextBlock(required=True, help_text='Add text here')

    class Meta:
        templates = 'streams/title_and_text_block.html'
        icon = 'edit'
        label = 'Title & Text'
```

This is the last template that works, and it should tie into the above code and the template that does not work.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        {{ self.subtitle }}
    </div>

{% for block in page.content %}
    {% include_block block %}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

And this is some dummy text in the template that doesn't work
"Put Anything In here."
I appreciate any and all help and if I've given too much code, or not enough, please let me know.

The About (or flex) page, should show "Put anything in here." But nothing shows.

Comment: In your block meta class, it should be `template` not `templates` ([docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/topics/streamfield.html?highlight=streamfield#basic-block-types))

Comment: Tried that, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It worked. Thanks, I had to refresh the page after making the corrections